# Cocoa how to change label text in second view when a button is clicked in the first view

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, view, label

I am quite new to xcode and don't know that much about.
I am making a app where you enter text into a textField in the First View and then click a button and will change the text of the label in the Second View.

This is the code.(small version) 
First View code.

```
    #import "SecondViewController.h"  
    - (IBAction)Settext:(id)sender;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
    @implementation FirstViewController 

    - (IBAction)Settext:(id)sender {
    self.text = self.textField.text;
    self.label.text = self.text


    }
    @end
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a string property in second view class.while calling the second view set the string value.Use the value from the `viewDidLoad` in secovd view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use segues. These had me confused for a while, but they really aren't bad. When you tap the button, you need to trigger a segue (which just means the view is moving to the other controller) You then #import the .h of the second view controller like you have done. Then use the -(void)prepareForSeuge method as shows below

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{    
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        YourViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        //This is where you would set the text from the second view controller to what you want
       vc.yourText = @"What ever you need it to be";
    }
}
```

you will need to make an @property called yourText for the NSString in the second viewcontroller